# Book about a one-eyed hero in a post-apocalyptic world with colonies of telepathic semi-sentient ants

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic

I read this book in the mid-70's.

The hero had one eye, as his other was clawed out by a bear when his weapon malfunctioned. It is set in a post-apocalyptic world with colonies of telepathic, semi-sentient ants.

Comment: This is a bit on the terse side so could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? It might also be worth taking a look at the [tour].